# Why does this method cause infinite recursion?

Tags: java

```
public static int func(int n){
    int result ;
    result = func(n - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Why do I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

when I call this method?

Comment: Well what would you *expect* to happen? How would you expect it to ever terminate?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? You always call `func` inside the `func` method. When do you think will the program reach the `return`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion

Comment: You never defined an exit condition, so your recursion does not know, when to stop.

Comment: btw, why spread this over three lines and declare a local variable, when all it does is return a call value?

Comment: I need to know why this method cause infinite loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func` is always calling itself. There is no stopping condition. Each call creates a new stack frame, until the call stack is full and `StackOverflowError` is thrown.

Recursive methods should always have a stopping condition. For example - `n < 0` :

```
public static int func(int n){
    int result;
    if (n >= 0)
        result = func(n - 1);
    else
        result = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot  Mr.Eran